# Explicit example of elliptic curve of the kind needed for IUTT

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, abc-conjecture

At the nLab, we are currently trying to illustrate the definition of initial theta-data in Mochizuki's first IUTT paper by means of an explicit example. The exposition should end up at the following page, but there is hardly anything there yet.

[nLab:initial $\Theta$-data](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+%CE%98-data)

What I mean by an explicit example is an actual Weierstrass equation over some specific extension of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ for an elliptic curve E satisfying the assumptions of the definition of initial theta-data in Definition 3.1 of [IUTT I](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/Inter-universal%20Teichmuller%20Theory%20I.pdf) (pdf), together with explicit examples of/discussion of the remaining parts of the 7-tuple that defines initial theta-data.

Even very basic things like a fully worked out, completely explicit, example of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ with good reduction at all non-archimedean valuations would be helpful. [Edit: according to the comments, no such elliptic curve exists. However, in the definition of initial theta-data, it is asked only that a *once-punctured* elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has good reduction at all non-archimedean valuations. This was omitted in the original question for simplicity. Does this change things?]

The example need not have any wider significance within IUTT.

In private correspondence, Professor Mochizuki was encouraging about the creation of this nLab page, and suggested that "most"/"suitably generic" elliptic curves and primes $\ell$ should satisfy the definition of initial theta-data. He also pointed to Corollary 2.2 (ii) in IUTT IV, in which initial theta-data is constructed from an elliptic curve. An alternative to giving an explicit example from first principles would be to spell out gently what is happening in the proof of this corollary.

Allow me to emphasise that we are looking very much for things to be completely explicit; general methods for constructing examples are without doubt very interesting, but I think for expository purposes spelling out one example in detail would be what is most helpful to the most people. If it is helpful, assume some background in algebraic geometry, but little to none in number theory, however naïve this may be.

Comment: It is not clear what this question is asking for. You should list the assumptions needed. Elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ are listed here http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/2.0.4.1/?start=0&count=50&field=2.0.4.1; none has good reduction everywhere I think.

Comment: The elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+x$ (or any other CM elliptic curve) has good reduction everywhere over an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which can be explicitly determined from Tate's algorithm. In fact, see exercise 7.5 of Silverman AEC for an explicit field.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch sure, but this is looking for not just "an extension", but a specific given extension. How would one reverse engineer a curve so that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is the extension that works? I feel this latter question is implicit in the OP.

Comment: @DavidRoberts It's not clear to me that there exists an elliptic curve with good reduction everywhere over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: Indeed, there isn't : B. SETZER, Elliptic curves over complex quadratic fields. Pacific J. Math. 74, 235 - 250 (1978)

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: Also Fontaine's theorem includes the statement that there is no abelian scheme over neither $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ nor $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. (Edit: we were writing at the same time, but I'll leave this comment for its supplementary reference.)

Comment: @FelipeVoloch well, that's good to know, in the context of the question. But the idea is not good reduction everywhere, but over all non-archimedean places. Surely examples like the OP asks for would be nice to have, given that there have been....comments about the lack of examples in the IUTT papers?

Comment: Good reduction at all non-archimedean places is precisely the definition of good reduction everywhere.

Comment: @KeerthiMadapusiPera thanks, that's not obvious to me, a non-number theorist, and casual bystander

Comment: Given a rumour I've just read, I'm no longer sure how useful this thread answer may be...

Comment: But Mochizuki's definition is about punctured elliptic curves, so maybe there is one with good reduction after all.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: That makes no difference, since 'punctured' means punctured at the zero section.

Comment: As someone who spent some time with anabelian geometry - but who doesn't understand IUT! - I think it is highly unlikely that knowing an explicit example of the elliptic curve in the initial theta data will prove useful. The cornerstone theorem of anabelian geometry (on which IUTeich is based) states that number fields can be reconstructed by their Galois groups (Neukirch-Uchida). One could naively ask for an 'explicit' reconstruction, but any such reconstruction has to come to terms with the fact that the input datum is the absolute Galois group of Q.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Are you referring to https://totallydisconnected.wordpress.com/2018/05/09/the-latest-hot-abc-news/ ?

Comment: Mochizuki uses the word "stable" in his definition of initial theta data, which is usually taken to mean "good"; however, is it possible he's taking it to mean "semistable" instead, and not just good reduction? Mochizuki is going to use Tate parameters in IUT and I thought we only have that for curves with split multiplicative reduction?

In the case that "stable" actually means "semistable", the following curve should satisfy the conditions for initial theta data:

http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/14/a/3

Comment: @S.Carnahan well, number theorists seem to be rather secretive, so until something is public ..... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: It was remarked elsewhere that "over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$" should have been "over a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$", in which case I retract my quibbles.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: On your first comment, it turns out a general fact that, more precisely, every elliptic curve $E/F$ with CM by the *full* integer ring $O_k$ of a quadratic field $k$ has good reduction at all places of $F$ of residue characteristic $\neq 2, 3$. This follows by an application of Shimura's reciprocity law (essentially known to Weber in this case) as described in the key *Lemma 1* of Granville and Stark's paper *ABC implies no Siegel zeros for...* (although they don't use the language of elliptic curves). The mod $6$ ray class field of $k$ attains good reduction everywhere.